# DOCKER> Unable to build image : The command returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: maven, docker, virtualbox

I'm running Docker on Windows 10 machine with Vagrant and VirtualBox.

During my Maven build I got a following exception:

```
DOCKER> Unable to build image : The command returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I can ssh to Docker VM. How to get detailed logs from Docker in order to determine what goes wrong?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a Windows 10 machine which runs as VirtualBox VM (with Vagrant) which itself runs Docker ? (seems obvious but just in case). When and where is your Maven build? It seems you are trying to use Maven to build a Docker image, is that so? If yes please share the Maven command you are running along with the pom.xml (and parent poms as well if any), along with maximum details ;)

Comment: `docker container logs <containerName> -f ` will give you the logs detail of your container.